# How to set the tip dimensions with jQuery qTIp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, qtip

I'm having some trouble with modifying qTip's tip size (x,y).
I tried to add the `style: { tip: { x:2,y:2 } }` in all sorts of ways, but failed.

How can I add it to the following script?

```
  // Status Tooltips Style
  $.fn.qtip.styles.statusTooltips = {
    background: '#333333',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    border: {
      width: 1,
      radius: 5,
      color: '#333333'
    },
    tip: 'leftMiddle',
    name: 'dark'
  }

  // Status Tooltips Init
  $('.status[title]').qtip({
    style: 'statusTooltips',
    position: {
      corner: {
         target: 'rightMiddle',
         tooltip: 'leftBottom'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: qTip's documenation on this: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#style

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's simpe enough:

```
$("#mytip").qtip({style: { tip: { size: { x: 10, y: 10}} }});
```

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#tips

Comment: You must imagine I've tried this before posting my question to the StackOverflow community, yes?

Comment: Yes, but since you left out the "size"-object in your question, i thought might have missed that for some reason, stranger things have happened. Sorry if you felt insulted.

Answer (score 4):

For qtip 2, you can just set the `width` and `height` properties of the `tip` object:

```
$("#mytip").qtip({
    style: {
        tip: {
            width: 10,
            height: 10
        }
    }
});
```

See http://qtip2.com/plugins#tips.width

Answer (score -6):

Got it!

```
  $('.status[title]').qtip({
    style: {background:'#333333',
      color:'white',
      textAlign:'center',
      border:{width: 1, radius: 5, color: '#333333'},
      tip:{corner:'leftMiddle',size: { x:6,y:10 }}
    },
    position: {corner: {target:'rightMiddle',tooltip:'leftBottom'}}
  });
```

Thanks, StackOverflow, for being an occasional [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)